# Unsafe call of an `any` typed value. Importing function from a javascript file

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

I am importing two functions from a javascript file. ES lint errors on one of them claiming its an "unsafe call of an `any` typed value". However the other one is fine (despite being more complex).

```js
  type Indices = { source: number; destination: number };

  const handleDragEnd = (event: DragEndEvent) => {

    const indices: Indices = getIndices(event);

    const cols: DefaultColumnType[] = reorderItems(
      indices,
      defaultColumns,
      updateDefaultColumnMutation
    );
...
```

`reorderItems` and `getIndices` are both untyped, from a js file. `reorderItems` is more complex, however doesn't receive the ES lint error that `getIndices` does. Any help on how to get rid of the warning would be much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far to get rid of the warning? You can add comments to tell eslint to stop showing a warning for a line.

Comment: So i ended converting that entire js file to ts and now it works. Not sure why one func could be imported but the other couldnt. It could possibly be because `reorderItems` has some default parameters that eslint possibly treats as "defined enough", as default parameters are inherently typed. Whereas `getIndices` just takes a required arg, so 100% of the args (1/1) are `any` typed? - just a theory